# Is it possible to pass a template function as argument without filling its own arguments?

Tags: c++, templates

Sorry if the question looks stupid. But I have the following code that compiles. I was wondering if it's possible to pass only the name of the function as template and then later on fill it in the function? Like for example in here we have

```
template<typename T>
    int getDiscount(T t,const std::vector<int> & discounts) {
        return t(discounts);
    }
```

Is it possible to just pass in the `main`like `getDiscount(discount.getMaxDiscount)` without getting a compilation error? I am working on C++11

---

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

class Discount {
    public:
      Discount() {}
      int getMaxDiscount(const std::vector<int> & discounts) {
          return *max_element(discounts.begin(),discounts.end());
      }
      int getMinDiscount(const std::vector<int> & discounts) {
          return *max_element(discounts.begin(),discounts.end());
      }
};

int getMinDiscount(const std::vector<int> & discounts){
    Discount discount;
    return discount.getMinDiscount(discounts);
}
int getMaxDiscount(const std::vector<int> & discounts){
    Discount discount;
    return discount.getMaxDiscount(discounts); 
}

template<typename T>
int getDiscount(T t,const std::vector<int> & discounts) {
    return t(discounts);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> discs = {1,2,3,4};
    std::cout << getMaxDiscount(discs) << std::endl;

    Discount discount;
    std::cout << getDiscount(discount.getMaxDiscount) << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `discount.getMaxDiscount` is not a function pointer, you have to use Lambda to get this behavior. Also have a look on `std::bind` (and also have a look to static function, your class member functions has no reason no to be static)

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.  I tried to simply the code as much I can. The are other Much more complicated stuff inside. But that's the only example that I found

Comment: it's an update based on Jarods answer. Did u read his answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might do:

```
std::cout << getDiscount(std::mem_fn(&Discount::getMaxDiscount), discount) << std::endl;
```

or with lambda:

```
std::cout << getDiscount([](const Discount& discount){ return discount.getMaxDiscount()), discount) << std::endl;
```